# Solve:$ 45=-21.9*cos(\frac {\pi}{6}(t-1))+51.6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm interested in learning how to solve this without a graphing calculator.

For $t = 0$ to $12$,

$$ 45=-21.9\cdot\cos(\frac {\pi}6(t-1))+51.6$$

Comment: There are two solutions for this question.

Comment: Can you evaluate $\cos(n\frac{\pi}{6})$ for $n$ an integer? Can you do it for $n=0$? for $n=1$?

Answer (score 0):

If $t \in [0,12]$, then $\frac {\pi}{6}(t-1) \in [-\frac {\pi}{6},\frac {11\pi}{6}]$.

$45=-21.9*cos(\frac {\pi}{6}(t-1))+51.6 \iff \frac {6,6}{21.9} = cos(\frac {\pi}{6}(t-1))$.

$\arccos(\frac {6,6}{21.9})$ gives $\frac {\pi}{6}(t-1)$ satisfying the equation for $\frac {\pi}{6}(t-1) \in [0,\pi]$. From there you obtain easily the value of $t$. Using the symetrie and the periodicity of $\cos$, you obtain the other solution of the equation which lays in $[-\frac {\pi}{6},0] \cup [\pi,\frac {11\pi}{6}]$.